# How can I create an Android end-to-end test for a specific user flow?

Tags: android, end-to-end, android-instrumentation

The aim is to create end-to-end tests for a native Android app, that allows us to validate the "happy path" and alleviate our QA burden of manually carrying out these tasks.

In the project, we already have unit tests, UI tests created with `Espresso`, and tests for other components such as view models and data layers that utilize `JUnit`. What I need now, for an application that should allow a user to fill and complete a survey:

**How can I best automate the creation of a questionnaire?** When a user logs in, I fetch all the questions, and related entities (synchronize) while in the `DashboardActivity` (Here API calls are made and various entities are stored in the local DB), then navigate to the `QuestionnaireActivity` (form).

In the questionnaire, I want to simulate answering, by plugging in standard answers for the different question types. Also a lot of validation goes on here, and I want to be able to test things like, whether questions are saved correctly to the DB, simulate back navigation, and eventually submit the questionnaire i.e. upload to the server, in the `UploadActivity`, and finally navigate back to the dashboard (where new questionnaires are started).

My impression so far has been that I need something beyond mocking which caused me to rule out tools like `MockWebServer`.

**How can I persist the data that I load from the server during synchronization, so I can utilize it throughout this entire flow?** I can so far perform clicks via Espresso to trigger the sync, but once it's done in that activity, I am still looking for a way to have access to that data.

**Does this entire process also require me to fix the order in which the instrumentation tests are run? How can I go about that?**

**If I am to place these new tests in the `androidTest` package, how would I run them separate from the usual tests I already have in the package?** I'd prefer some kind of isolation, to avoid triggering long jobs whenever the instrumentation tests are run.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator

Comment: Search for test `@RunWith(Suite::class)` and `@Suite.SuiteClasses(...`. In short separate your "happyFlowEnd2End" tests into its own Suite. Ultimately they are just Espresso tests that use (most likely) something like the [testing robots](https://jakewharton.com/testing-robots/) to follow the whole flow.